# Class 'App\imports\ExcelImport' not found , in laravel excel import case

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

import class

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class ExcelImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Excel([
            'name' => $row[0],
            'email' => $row[1],
            'password' => Hash::make($row[2]),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Admin\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

use App\imports\ExcelImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

use DB;
use Validator;
use session;

class ImportExcelController extends Controller
{
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx,csv'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
        }else{

            $file = $request->file;
             
            $data = Excel::import(new ExcelImport, $file);

            return redirect()->back()->with('message','File uploaded successfully');
        }

            

    }
}
```

showing

```
Class 'App\imports\ExcelImport' not found , line "$data = Excel::import(new ExcelImport, $file);"
```

Why am I getting this error still? I have imported the excel class already in the controller.

Help me to find out this issue.

Comment: Laravel probably uses PSR-4 autoloading, which is case sensitive. Try `use App\Imports\ExcelImport;`

Answer (score 0):

Run the command: composer dump-autoload and try.

Answer (score 0):

Make the this

```
use App\imports\ExcelImport;
```

To

```
use App\Imports\ExcelImport;
```

Seems like a speeling mistake.